# What is a homogeneous tree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

A tree is a graph without cycles, but what does the additional word "homogeneous" mean?

Comment: Homogeneous in general means all the vertices "look the same" in terms of the graph structure. Precisely, it means each vertex has the same degree/valency.

Comment: That would mean the tree is $K_{2}$ or $K_{1}$. I assume it means that all non-leaf vertices have the same degree.

Comment: I think it is important to note a *tree* is a ***connected**, acyclic graph*. I have never known of, and can find no reference to homogeneous trees in graph theory, but there's a good chunk of results coming up for set theory (including a few questions on MathOverflow). Possibly you've heard the term out of context?

Comment: @mathworker21 A graph in which each vertex has the same degree is called *regular*. A regular *tree* is homogeneous (all vertices look the same) but in general a regular graph need not be homogeneous.

Comment: @Nij For $k\ge2$ there is a $k$-regular (and so homogeneous) connected acyclic graph (tree). Is the study of infinite graphs part of graph theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly tree is a *connected* graph without cycles. As it is mentioned in comments *finite* regular tree is either $K_2$ or $K_1$. However term *homogeneous tree* concerns not finite, but locally finite trees. A tree $T$ is *locally finite* if set $N(v)$ of vertices adjacent to $v$ is finite for all $v \in V(T)$. Locally finite tree is *homogeneous* of degree $d$ if each vertex is incident to $d$ edges. See more in book "[Harmonic Analysis for Anisotropic Random Walks on Homogeneous Trees](https://books.google.by/books?id=DozUCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=homogeneous+tree+graph&source=bl&ots=G_s7hwWbAg&sig=hVzedLV1L2b9SnX0qkbGgK1LjOw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiux6GK6crTAhXDCJoKHcHuAMEQ6AEIRzAE#v=onepage&q=homogeneous%20tree%20graph&f=false)" by Alessandro Figà-Talamanca and Tim Steger.